# Selecting only users who have at least one similar many to 1 relationship SQL query modification

Tags: javascript, sql, select, azure, where-clause

Currently i have the sql query

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM [epicatest].[User] WHERE longitude != \'null\' AND latitude != \'null\' AND id != \'' + userId + '\'';
```

This will return:
**id:
surname:
firstname:
dob:
longitude:
latitude:
email:**

I also have another table called [epicatest].[User_Sports] and inside this there are the fields:
**id:
sport_id**

before the query above is called, i have an array stored which contains a list of sports id which are associated with you (origin user).

when the query is called, i would like to expand it so that it only selects the people who share **at least one** common sport with you (i.e they have an (id), VALUES (sport_id) which you also have

heres an example of what im trying to do, imagine origin user has id of 1

id, sport_id

**1, sport a**

**1, sport b**

**1, sport c**

2, sport a

3, sport f

2, sport g

3, sport l

3, sport h

4, sport c

4, sport h

2, sport k

4, sport z

so if i ran a 'query' it would return only the users with id, 2 and 4, as they are interested in sport a and c, the same as me(origin user). This is what i am trying to achieve, how would i modify this:

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM [epicatest].[User] WHERE longitude != \'null\' AND latitude != \'null\' AND id != \'' + userId + '\'';
```

to do so?

remember i have an array available to me with all my (origin user) sport_ids

Thanks.

Comment: A couple of questions: what DBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...)? Are you storing the users' sports preferences in a table in the same DB? What's the name of that table?

Comment: @Stefano Dalpiaz

Microsoft Azure, it uses MS SQL.

In the database we have the tables:
[User] - which stores the id, surename, first name etc.
[Sports] - which stores and id, and name (i.e. bowling, swimming etc)
[User_Sport] - a table which is used to manage a many to many relationship, in here we store the [user].id and the [Sports].id

Comment: Ok I had already replied with a couple of assumptions. Let me change it with the new names.

Comment: Not really an Azure question.

Comment: I put it as azure as thats the platform im using for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you are using Azure, so I am using SQL Server syntax. Also, I am assuming that the table User_Sport has a couple of columns called *user_id* and *sport_id*.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.* FROM
    [epicatest].[User] u
INNER JOIN
    [epicatest].[User_Sport] p ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE
    u.longitude != 'null'
AND
    u.longitude != 'null'
AND
    u.id != @user_id
AND
    p.sports_id IN (1, 2, 3) -- this is the list of your sport IDs, comma-seprated
```

Comment: we dont have a preferences table, we have a table called [User_Sport] which contains a foreign key (id) from the [User] table and foreign key (id) from the [Sports] table 

i.e

Id  =  [user].id (FK)
sport_id = [Sport.id](FK).

Is you 'Preferences' table what our [User_Sport] table is in terms of layout?

regards
Jordan

Comment: Yes, Preferences is the name I gave your User_Sport table before you told me it was called like that. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I'll give this a try now, thank you very much for the help so far!